# Clustering and grouping of rhythmic data (acrophases)

Tags: clustering, missing-data, circular-statistics, cosinor

I am looking for suggestions towards a clustering method for rhythmic/oscillation data.
We performed cosinor regression (`sin(2*pi*time/period)+cos(2*pi*time/period)`) over a 24h period (the context here is gene expression data, data acquired at 6 timepoints) and then calculated acrophases (so the timepoint of peak expression of the wave) based on the model coefficients for those elements that were significantly rhythmic. This yields a matrix as the following, values being the acrophase (between 0 and 23.9999) and NA if that element was not significantly rhythmic.

```r
df <- structure(list(sample_1 = c(10.2067908949366, 9.57794304686272, 
10.2296692582844, 9.44587084324263, 1.43812935645521, 7.99515076795777
), sample_2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), sample_3 = c(4.88994944807256, NA, NA, 18.6683039785972, 
NA, NA), sample_4 = c(NA, 23.2915750283631, 2.37461681543813, 
NA, 3.58684020625613, 23.9046720435592), sample_5 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), sample_6 = c(13.601642965999, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sample_7 = c(18.8254052034793, NA, NA, 23.7351141037999, 
1.17111327847434, NA), sample_8 = c(NA, NA, NA, 10.1658308244718, 
3.66084900898831, NA), sample_9 = c(6.61434576795531, NA, 7.22338137402851, 
21.0233649696896, 2.52602778930659, NA), sample_10 = c(NA, NA, 
10.4146070426224, 1.3147998403721, NA, NA), sample_11 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), sample_12 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.21113156860509, NA)), row.names = c("element_1", 
"element_2", "element_3", "element_4", "element_5", "element_6"
), class = "data.frame")

           sample_1 sample_2  sample_3  sample_4 sample_5 sample_6  sample_7  sample_8  sample_9 sample_10 sample_11 sample_12
element_1 10.206791       NA  4.889949        NA       NA 13.60164 18.825405        NA  6.614346        NA        NA        NA
element_2  9.577943       NA        NA 23.291575       NA       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
element_3 10.229669       NA        NA  2.374617       NA       NA        NA        NA  7.223381  10.41461        NA        NA
element_4  9.445871       NA 18.668304        NA       NA       NA 23.735114 10.165831 21.023365   1.31480        NA        NA
element_5  1.438129       NA        NA  3.586840       NA       NA  1.171113  3.660849  2.526028        NA        NA  4.211132
element_6  7.995151       NA        NA 23.904672       NA       NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Now: I would like to bring both elements and samples together if they have similar acrophases, aiming to find patterns. Essentially something like "elements(x,y,z) have similar acrophases in samples(a,b,c)". Yet I am unsure which approach would be appropriate, especially given the NAs. The NAs are present because calculation of acrophase is only accurate if an element is rhythmic (and the NA elements are not rhythmic for that given sample), and I cannot put it to zero as zero itself is a valid acrophase value (range 0-23.9999). Would you please recommend any approach to group these data by similarity of acrophase.

Note: Since these are rhythmic/oscillation data an acrophase of 23.9999 is basically the same as one of 0 (period of 24, so after 23.999 it starts at 0 again), hence method must be aware of that.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what are the "elements" and what are the "samples". And also, why you prefer to do a similarity assessment after the cosinor/regression and not before it on the raw "time series" data.

Comment: @ttnphns Samples are the specimen that were measured, a donor (in this case a mouse from which we extracted RNA for various organs). An element is an observation (in this case a gene, the matrix holds about 15k genes/rows/observations). The reason I do not do assessment on the "raw" data as you call it is that the gene expression in RNA-seq (that is the experiment we do) is widely different between genes, even after standardization the level of noise might introduce (in this case) meaningless patterns. Hence, I want to focus on these model-derived acrophases. Does that clarify?

Comment: Assuming you want a dissimilarity between genes (elements) not mice (samples). Maybe: 1) Each value (acrophase time) split into the sin and the cos, like you would split a degree on the clock shown by the hour-hand into vertical and horizontal gauges. 2) Consider each sample, i.e., the sin and the cos, a separate dataset, and compute the matrix of euclidean distances (that is, chord distances in this case) between all the genes, pairwisely. Computation is possible of course where both genes of the pair has data (acrophase is not NA for both).

Comment: (cont.) 3) So, you end up with such a square symmetric matrix for each sample, some cells in the matrix being computed distances and some being NA. 4) Average corresponding cells across the matrices. You finish with the single matrix with the mean euclidean distances.

Comment: You say you have 15K genes. While 15Kx15K matrices are computable, you may possibly want first to get rid of the genes that only seldom show acrophases.

Comment: The final distance matrix between the genes can be processed by a cluster analysis or by mds. Similar genes are similar because they have similar acrophases in the same samples. Which were these samples and the magnitudes of acrophases - you find when consider the similar, same cluster genes together, their "profiles".